# Open multiple Google Map marker infoboxes on page load

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get it so that the infoboxes on my custom Google Map are open on pageload.

I currently have this:

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: pinimage
          });

                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Which only opens one info box but not the other two (there are three in total). I'm not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because your infowindow needs to be within your for loop, as its outside, only one will get created and so the content and marker its being used for gets overwritten on each iteration of your loop.

It needs to go just after where the marker is created.

```
var infowindow, marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: pinimage
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```